# is contour going out of business?

Tags: camera

I use a contour camera while a bike.
Recently all contour videos stopped working, and now their site seems very flakey.

Asking this here because Help/Support is broken there. (close if really off-topic)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a camera company.

Comment: I would say this question is valid for this site given that the cameras are made with mounting on bicycles in mind, and many users of this site has either done it or want to do it.  If it was about Nikon or Cannon where going away, then kick it to the other SE site.

Comment: @BPugh While they might make some bike specific products, they're a camera company first. They list bike, snow, air, motor, water, tactical, hike & climb, and skate on their [products page](http://contour.com/products/compare_cameras). Anyway, it's in the hands of the community now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, they're done, but perhaps not out as another company may pick up the brand/product. Check out the article on [GeekWire](http://www.geekwire.com/2013/contour-closes-seattle-hq-surprises-employees-execs-mum-status-gopro-rival/).

Comment: that sucks. wish they would have given me some heads up about deleting all my videos

Comment: Bummer! I always liked the design of their cam, but the GoPro apparently has pushed them out. Check out Sony's ActionCam or Garmin's new cam, they both look good too.